# Rails cannot write to database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do a very simple update on a field that does not have any validation whatsoever. However, the update always fails. Here is what the code looks like:

```
# model
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :start_time

  ..

end

# migration
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    t.datetime :start_time
  end
end

# console
Event.first.update_attribute(:start_time, "02:00")
```

The query that was run in the Rails log does not even include the start_time attribute!

> (0.2ms)  BEGIN
>
> (4.5ms) UPDATE `events` SET `updated_at` =
>   '2012-07-24 19:51:33', `repeat_days` = '--- \n- wed\n- sat\n- sun\n',
>   `event_date_list` = '--- []\n\n' WHERE `events`.`id` = 3763
>
> (5.5ms) COMMIT

I cannot begin to make sense of this. Can anyone help me understand the root cause of this problem?

Comment: does start_time show in the schema.rb, what if you look at the tables in the db, does events have a start_time field? Was start_time included in the original migration or added afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

You are a passing it a string, not a Date, Time, or Datetime object.

It looks like you just want to store the time, not the date attached. But maybe you meant to attach a date as well. If you want to store the date as well, look up the Datetime class.

If you want to store just the time (hours, minutes, and seconds), then I would suggest you change your `start_time` field to be an integer, and store the seconds: `2.hours` or `2.hours + 4.minutes + 6.seconds`.

You can convert that easily in to time again.